# GitHub - README.md Windows editor?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I have lots of libs on GitHub and would like to write README.md for all of them.
Im doing  this by writing into README.md on my local repo, and then pushing it to github, and there I can see changes.

Is there any other way of doing this?
Is there some Windows editor so I can write README.md and all the tags on local PC and see who would README.md output look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I prefer [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/). It provides you with a nice preview window on side of the actual markdown code:

[image]

Note that if you want to make it compliant with Github's own markdown syntax, you need to additionally install [markdownpad-github](https://github.com/nicolahery/markdownpad-github).

**Edit:** MarkdownPad 2 Pro has announced support for Github flavored markdown: http://markdownpad.com/news/2013/introducing-markdownpad-2/

Comment: Looks awesome. Can it recognize syntax like github can, using '''''php some code'''''?

Comment: Oh dang. Seems like you are still gonna miss some features like syntax highlighting: https://github.com/nicolahery/markdownpad-github. But I gotta say, I've been a happy user nonetheless.

Comment: Hey - developer of MarkdownPad here. Just wanted to let you know that GitHub syntax highlighting will be available in MarkdownPad this week :)

Comment: @jsalonen Thanks for posting the link to the announcement! :)

Comment: Sadly, this project seems to have died. Latest version is of 2015 and won't run on Windows 10

Comment: A vivid alternative might be [ghostwriter](https://github.com/wereturtle/ghostwriter).

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has a pretty nice built-in markdown editor and live preview. You can just snap the preview tab on the right (or left if you're that kind of person) to see your changes as you make them.

[image: README.md editing on VS Code]

Answer (score 0):

I would add [MaNo](https://github.com/mougino/MaNo) to the list of options on WindowsTM. Very lightweight at 270k. Not wysiwig, but F5 to generate HTML and load into default viewer. [MaNo Markdown notepad editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPbjD.jpg)

Command line options to generate html file, load in browser and quit - use MaNo as a Markdown viewer.

Kind Regards Gavin Holt